# CSS input button on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css

I have this site here http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/?page_id=5 and in the top right corner I have an input button and it looks weird on an iphone and I don't know why. It makes into a circle/bubble like button.

Heres the HTML for the input button

```
<input type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="searchBtn" value="GO"/>
```

and here is the CSS

```
.searchBtn{
    background-color:#ffa18a;
    color:#FFF;
    height:31px;
    padding:0;
    width:32px;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: seems fine on my iPhone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed my problem but adjusting my css like this...

```
.searchBtn{
    background-color:#ffa18a;
    color:#FFF;
    height:31px;
    padding:0;
    width:32px;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

By adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` the button now looks good an iphone, this also works for the iPad.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of different buttons that this is an issue with on your site, try:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

That should reset all of your input buttons without causing problems with checkboxes and other inputs. Just leave the rest of your CSS as-is.

consider setting -moz-appearance and -ms-appearance to none as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a mac you can turn on developer tools in Safari and put the browser into iPhone simulation mode and try to debug it that way.